# Lightning controller action not working for an specific user

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, action

I have a code that enqueue one lightning action. This code is working fine for my System Administrator user but if I try calling it from any other user it retrieves this:

**Se ha producido un error interno en el servidor Id. del error: 1944253861-189643 (-221122246)**

This is my js function:

```
callActions : function(component, event, helper){
    var params;
    var result;
    var message;
    component.set("v.isLoading",true);
    var stage = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    var action = component.get("c.checkActionConditions");
    var header = component.get("v.actionHeaderMAP")[stage];
    console.log('***header: ' + JSON.stringify(header));
    action.setParams({
        "recordId" : component.get("v.recordId"),
        "logicConditions" : header.hasOwnProperty('logicConditions') ? header.logicConditions : null,
        "message" : header.hasOwnProperty('message') ? header.message : null,
        "conditionLIST" : header.hasOwnProperty('conditionLIST') ? header.conditionLIST : null,
        "parentAction" : header.hasOwnProperty('parentAction') ? header.parentAction : null
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        if(response.getState() === 'SUCCESS'){
            result = response.getReturnValue();
            if(result.success){
                //Start processing
                if(header.hasOwnProperty('actionHeaderStepLIST') && header.actionHeaderStepLIST.length > 0){
                    component.set("v.header", header);
                    helper.manageActionsOneByOne(component);    
                }   
                //No actions to process
                else{
                    message = 'No se encuentran acciones a gestionar para el proceso ' + header.name;
                    params = {"title":"Error","message":message,"duration":5000,"type":"error"};
                    helper.generateToast(params);
                    component.set("v.isLoading",false);
                }
            }
            else{
                message = result.message;
                params = {"title":"Error","message":message,"duration":5000,"type":"error"};
                helper.generateToast(params);
                component.set("v.isLoading",false);
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log('****error:  '+ JSON.stringify(response.getError()));
            message = helper.getErrorMessage(response.getError()[0]);
            params = {"title":"Error","message":message,"duration":5000,"type":"error"};
            helper.generateToast(params);
            component.set("v.isLoading",false);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

And this is my controller function (without sharing class):

```
@AuraEnabled
public static BI_LEX_GenericApprovalActionControl.response checkActionConditions(String recordId, String logicConditions, String message, List<BI_LEX_Condition__c> conditionLIST, String parentAction){
    BI_LEX_GenericApprovalActionControl.response result = new BI_LEX_GenericApprovalActionControl.response();
    String query;
    String auxString;
    //Auxiliar BI_LEX_Condition__c record
    BI_LEX_Condition__c cd;
    List<SObject> checkLIST;
    Boolean byPassParent = true;
    //Map of condition by BI_LEX_Numero_condicion__c or generic index (if logicConditions has no value)
    Map<String,String> conditionByNumberMAP = new Map<String,String>();
    //For boolean values check
    Set<String> booleanSET = new Set<String>{'true','false'};
    //Check parent action if found
    if(parentAction != null){
        result = BI_LEX_GenericApprovalActionControl.parentActionCheck(parentAction);
        byPassParent = result.success;
    }
    //No parent action or parent action previously approved
    if(byPassParent){
        //Check conditions for record
        if(conditionLIST != null && !conditionLIST.isEmpty()){
            checkLIST = new List<SObject>();
            for(Integer i=0; i<conditionLIST.size(); i++){
                cd = conditionLIST[i];
                auxString = cd.BI_LEX_FieldAPIName__c + ' = ' + (cd.BI_LEX_FieldValue__c.isNumeric() || booleanSET.contains(cd.BI_LEX_FieldValue__c.toLowerCase()) ? cd.BI_LEX_FieldValue__c : '\'' + cd.BI_LEX_FieldValue__c + '\'');
                //Logic conditions and number of condition is not null
                if(logicConditions != null && !String.isEmpty(logicConditions) && cd.BI_LEX_Numero_condicion__c != null){
                    conditionByNumberMAP.put(String.valueOf(cd.BI_LEX_Numero_condicion__c), auxString);
                }
                //All conditions joined by AND
                else{
                    conditionByNumberMAP.put(String.valueOf(i), auxString);
                }
            }  
            //Get conditions (based on logic)
            if(logicConditions != null && !String.isEmpty(logicConditions)){
                //Replace conditions with valid ones
                List<String> charList = logicConditions.split('');
                for(String key : charLIST){
                    if(key.isNumeric() && conditionByNumberMAP.containsKey(key)){
                        charLIST[charLIST.indexOf(key)] = conditionByNumberMAP.get(key);
                    }
                }
                logicConditions = String.join(charLIST, '');
            }
            //Add them as AND string
            else{
                logicConditions = '';
                for(String key : conditionByNumberMAP.keySet()){
                    logicConditions += String.isEmpty(logicConditions) ? conditionByNumberMAP.get(key) : ' AND ' + conditionByNumberMAP.get(key);
                }
            }
            query = 'SELECT Id FROM ' + Id.valueOf(recordId).getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() + ' WHERE Id = :recordId AND ' + logicConditions;
            checkLIST = Database.query(query);
            result.success = checkLIST.isEmpty() ? false : true;
            result.message = checkLIST.isEmpty() ? message : null;
        }
        //No conditions to check
        else{
            result.success = true;
        }    
    }
    return result;
```

I've also checked debug logs for this user and no error is being displayed.

**Is it possible that same code runs successfully for one user but not for another?**

Comment: My Recommendation is that you envelope your code in a try-catch and throw an `AuraHandledException` with the message returned from `e.getMessage();`. That should give you a human-readable message

Comment: @SebastianKessel I already tried that but it's giving me same error. I think is happening because of the js but don't know the reason..

Comment: That error is thrown by Apex, not by JS. You could have a parameter type problem, but it could be a lot of things. Your code does not include the try catch... I recommend you leave it on just in case.

Comment: How are these new users different than SysAdmin? Do they have access to the class in question?

Comment: @SebastianKessel I checked apex class access for user's profile and that's it. My collegue didn't grant access to it. Thanks a lot! Post your comment as solution and I'll upvote!

Comment: Done! Thank you, and please accept too it so others find it when looking for a similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check three things:

- Parameter Order
- Parameter Type
- Access to class for all the users in question

As best practice, you could also add a `try-catch` block that returned an `AuraHandledException` with the message in question.